# Ajax call to another website

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension

For some reason when I run this simple javascript snippet I get the message "Error!  Status = 404 Message = error"

```html
callPHP(1)

function callPHP(args) 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://lectiogroupgenerator.esy.es/index.php",
        type: 'post',
        data: { "json" : JSON.stringify(args) },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {
            if (data)
            {
                alert(data);
                return data;
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Data is empty");
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr)
        {
            alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status + " Message = " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

My PHP file is just:

```html
<?php
?>
```

I'm guessing 404 implicates that the php could not be found, but it does exist and I have no clue why it can't find it maybe it has something to do with me making a google chrome extension?

Comment: You're not making it easy for us to help you. Is it inside a content script and you're on https site? What's in manifest.json? What do you see when you inspect the sent request in devtools Network panel? You'll probably need to do the request in a [background/event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) script but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Yes, it's executed from an https site. That's probably my problem.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the CORS issue. http://lectiogroupgenerator.esy.es/index.php doesn't allow cross origin HTTP requests.
If that's not the case try explicitly defining the website in the permissions in the manifest file to allow requests in and out to that website.

Comment: Already added it in permissions. How can I allow cross origin HTTP requests on my website?

Comment: Seems like CORS isn't of the issue here! Your website isn't accepting 'application/json' type data. It works if you remove the `dataType : "application/json"` line. Might be something wrong on the receiving end not the sending end.

Comment: You are sending plain text from the server as a response and expecting json text in the ajax request.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the case. No matter what I return it doesn't help. I think it has something to do with what wOxxOm said.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), it was solved when I got an SSL certificate for my website.